# ng-click doesn't work on objects with opacity:1;

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a `Angular` project where I tried to make a modal dialog window for login.

However the `ng-click` elements inside my modal doesn't fire the call. All the ones which is outside my modal works like they should.

How can this be?

**app.css**

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #F5F5F0);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #F5F5F0);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #F5F5F0);
}
```

**navbar.html**

```
<div class="navigationbar" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    ...

    <a href="#loginModal" ng-click="hello()"></a>     <!-- Works like a charm -->

    ...

    <div id="loginModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <form>
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-lg btn-login" ng-click="hello()">
                            Login
                        </button>     <!-- works like shite in high heels -->
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**navbar.controller.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('lunorthApp')
    .controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Auth, $window) {

        ...

        $scope.hello = function(){
            console.log('hello');
        };

        ...

    });
```

and a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michaeltotkorsgaard/t6jnsz16/13/) in order for you guys to play around with ^^

Comment: Any chance you could create a fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your CSS actually:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Events are not triggered in your `div`, thus not firing the `click event` on your `button`.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16423/) to make a comparison with and without the `pointer-events: none;` property.

Comment: That is the issue you are totally correct thanks ^^

However if I remove the `pointer-event: none;` the other buttons doens't work on my site. any suggestions?

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle. You just have to force the CSS of the button to be: `pointer-events: auto;` and the event will be triggered :)

Comment: I don't see any difference in the fiddle

Comment: Sorry Erazihel. I had to remove the `correct answer` due to me being unable to fix my problem even after fiddling around with your solution for a long time. I think you are correct however, I just don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I added a fiddle in order foryou to maybe show me directly which value should be where. Hope it's okay ^^